# Invalid numpy shape in keras model

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras

I would like to build a neural network which accepts a simple 1-dimensional input vector. However, the following code gives me an error:

```
import numpy as np  
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

input_ = Input((311,))
x = Dense(200)(input_)
output = Dense(100)(x)
nn = Model([input_], [output])
nn.compile('SGD', loss='mean_squared_error')
nn.predict(np.zeros(311))
```

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (311,) but got array with shape (1,)

This is strange to me because `print(np.zeros(311).shape)` prints `(311,)` as expected.

Changing `np.zeros(311)` to `np.zeros((311,))` doesn't change anything and replacing `Input((311,))` with `Input(311)` doesn't work, since `Input` expects a 
shape tuple:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

How do I properly provide a single-dimension vector to a keras model?

Comment: You mean **each training sample** is a single value like 2.76?

Comment: Have you tried: input_  = Input(shape=(311,)) ?

Comment: this model doesn't make much sense to me - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The first dimension for `predict` has to be the batch dimension, i.e. `predict(np.zeros(shape=(1, 311)))` should work.

Comment: @IonicSolutions Ah thank you, that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first dimension for `predict` has to be the batch dimension, i.e. `predict(np.zeros(shape=(1, 311)))` should work.

See the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#input) for more details.